# what does xml has more than 80 views actually mean

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout

I am new to Android and I am designing an app but then this warning message appeared

```
activity_main.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance
```

I have searched on Google and here as to what it means but every answer was specific to their projects. I just want to know why would you get this message in the first place and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

User interface performance is directly related to (among other things) the complexity of the View hierarchy being displayed. This warning message is simply letting you know that you have a lot of Views defined in this layout and that it could lead to UI performance problems. The solution is to look at your layout and considering how you can simplify the View hierarchy to achieve the desired results with fewer Views.  Or, alternatively, you can take this warning with a grain of salt and just test to verify whether performance is acceptable for your layout on the device(s) that you plan to support.

Comment: Further, to 'simplify' your layout, consider removing nested panels and replacing them with grids. This reduces the depth of the scene graph, reducing the steps-to-walk from top-most to bottom-most view and therefore increases performance.